# elastic's snapshot and restore module repository_exception

Tags: snapshot, elasticsearch, elk

I'm using [elk-docker](https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) and trying to follow [Snapshot And Restore | Elasticsearch Reference [2.4] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) and getting following error:

```
# curl --request PUT --data '{ "type": "fs", "settings": {"compress": true, "location": "/run/elasticsearch/backups" } }' localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup?pretty
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_exception",
      "reason" : "[my_backup] failed to create repository"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[my_backup] failed to create repository",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "creation_exception",
      "reason" : "Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, RepositoryException[[my_backup] location [/run/elasticsearch/backups] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty]\n  at org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository\n\n1 error",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "repository_exception",
        "reason" : "[my_backup] location [/run/elasticsearch/backups] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
#
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `path.repo` into `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
# grep path.repo elasticsearch.yml 
path.repo: /run/elasticsearch/backups
#
```

followed by `docker-compose build` & `docker-compose up`, and `curl` again:

```
# curl --request PUT --data '{ "type": "fs", "settings": {"compress": true, "location": "/run/elasticsearch/backups" } }' localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup?pretty
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
#
```